# Create mp4 from PowerPoint in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I'm working on a project that requires automation of a PowerPoint presentation export to a .mp4 format. I've figured out how to save a PowerPoint in the .mp4 format using powershell, but I have not been able to find any documentation on how to change the amount of seconds the slides remain on screen in the video using only powershell.

Current Code:

```
$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$Application.Visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$ThemePath = "C:\Users\Theme.potx"
$PPTXPath = "C:\Users\ExistingPresentation.pptx"
$SavePath = "C:\Users\MyPresentation.mp4"

$Presentation = $Application.Presentations.Open($ReportPath)
--Applies a theme for the slides
$Presentation.ApplyTemplate($ThemePath)
--Saves as a Video
$Presentation.SaveAs($SavePath, 39)
$Presentation.Close()
```

What I'm trying to target:

[image: Target]

EDIT: I've found a library within Windows PowerPoint that seems to contain a library of Classes that can be used to alter its members. One of the is "powerpoint.application," the following script should theoretically be possible per what Theo has suggested, though I get an error instead.

```
$SlideShowTransition = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.SlideShowTransition
$SlideShowTransition.AdvanceOnTime = $True
$SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime = 10

New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At line:1 char:13
+ $Whatever = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.SlideShowTransition
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Here is another [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJWSp.png) directly from the environment. For some reason, SlideShowTransition isn't showing up. I may be missing a reference...?

Comment: Just guessing because I don't have PowerPoint, but does this work: `$Presentation.Slides | ForEach-Object { $_.AdvanceOnTime = $true; $_.AdvanceTime   = 10 }` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, $Presentation.Slides doesn't appear to contain those properties...

Comment: $Presentation for me doesn't fit there. The path should be Application.ActivePresentation.Slides. Your Application is $Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't create $SlideShowTransition without using $Presentation because the latter represents the actual presentation, without that you can't set anything on it.
See the example on [MS official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slideshowtransition.advanceontime) how it uses ActivePresentation to do the setting.
How it works: if you search for ActivePresentation in the left search box, you see that it is under Application. So to refer to it the path is Application.ActivePresentation.Slides and after you can try Theo's method. I think as you have only 1 presentation open that is the active one. If not you need to dig more in the docs to activate your $Presentation.

Comment: Understood, the issue that I'm having is that I can't seem to access SlideShowTransition in any way to set the properties, mainly because I don't know how. The "With" Clause that's in the documentation doesn't work in Windows PowerShell ISE either.

Comment: The "With" Clause in VB is the current object (= $_ in PS).

Comment: You're both absolutely correct, but it won't come up in the Intellisense. I might be missing a reference of some kind. I'll add an edit to the original post with another screenshot.

Comment: Test it by running it, don't bother with intellisense. Are you referring to PS intellisense? Why would that offer you anything for Office library?

Comment: You're correct, I come from a C# background which relies heavily on Visual Studio's Intellisense. I was able to successfully export the pptx to an mp4.